# Преобразовать вид объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты, map, for

Всем доброго времени суток, вопрос наверное очень часто встречающийся, но подходящего ответа я не нашел, увы(
хочу привести объект к такому виду

```
actions = {
  add: 1,
  edit: 2
};
```

Исходный вид объекта:

```
actions = {
  0: { id: 1, name: 'add', colorId: 3},
  1: { id: 2, name: 'edit', , colorId: 5}
};
```

Делал так:

```
actions.map((action) => {
  let actionName = action.name;
  let actionId = action.id
  return {
    actionName: actionId
  }
});
```

но так не работает

Comment: а у объектов есть метод `map` что вы его используете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let result = {};
let actions = {
  0: { id: 1, name: 'add', colorId: 3},
  1: { id: 2, name: 'edit', colorId: 5}
};

for (let action of Object.values(actions)) {
  result[action.name] = action.id;
}

console.log(result);
```

Либо как-то так (упрощением уже существующего объекта):

```js
let actions = {
  0: { id: 1, name: 'add', colorId: 3},
  1: { id: 2, name: 'edit', colorId: 5}
};

Object.keys(actions).map(key => {
  actions[actions[key].name] = actions[key].id;
  delete actions[key];
});

console.log(actions);
```

Comment: спасибо тебе большое

Comment: @AndrzejRecoba, proszę bardzo